# Pixel Tracking for a django based email

Tags: python, html, django, image, email

I wanted to know, which of the emails, that I have sent to have opened the email.

Here is how I approach to solve the problem -

1. Create an image file in the html template that should be rendered.

   < img src="{{ tracking_url }}" height="1" width="1">
2. Once an email is opened a request will be made to a url, which will have base64 encoded url pattern:

   base64_pattern = r'([A-Za-z0-9+/]{4})*([A-Za-z0-9+/]{2}==|[A-Za-z0-9+/]{3}=)'

   url(r'^tracking/(?P{})/$'.format(base64_pattern), 'tracking_image_url', name='tracking_image_url'),
3. That URL will serve an image, and update the counter, as follows -

   TRANSPARENT_1_PIXEL_GIF = "\x47\x49\x46\x38\x39\x61\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\xff\xff\xff\x00\x00\x00\x21\xf9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x2c\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02\x44\x01\x00\x3b"

view -

```
def tracking_image_url(request, mail_64=None):
    eml = base64.b64decode(mail_64)
    // Update the counters in the DB table for the email address. 
    return HttpResponse(TRANSPARENT_1_PIXEL_GIF, content_type='image/gif')
```

I do all this, but can't track the opens, what am I missing?

Comment: `//Update the counters` that's a javascript/c comment. not python ;) But really, you need to notify something somewhere that your view has been served up. Whether you store it in a table or somewhere else. Ultimately you need to probably tell us what `Update the counters` means and provide more details in general.

Comment: this basically means, I update the open log for that email, in the database. You can assume it works well.

Comment: Have you tried placing an image generated like that in a real view within a template to check if it works outside an email?

Comment: Have you solve your problem? I have the same issue.

Comment: Same issue. Would like to know more?

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import base64
from django.http import HttpResponse

PIXEL_GIF_DATA = base64.b64decode(
b"R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAAAAAP///yH5BAEAAAAALAAAAAABAAEAAAIBRAA7")


def index(request):
   return HttpResponse(PIXEL_GIF_DATA, content_type='image/gif')
```